# Why does Google recommend using classes acting as functions for use cases?

Tags: android, kotlin, naming-conventions, naming

### Introduction

Semantically speaking, [classes and interfaces act as **nouns** and methods/functions act as **verbs**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN6qX.png). This is something that I recently read in the [Java to Kotlin](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-to-kotlin/9781492082262/) and it is aligned with how the vast majority of the people naturally name methods and classes.

For example we would expect a `Car` class to have a `getBrand` method, not a `GetBrand` class with an `invoke` method returning the brand of the car.

However, while reading the recent [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture#domain-layer) from Google, I have came across their [naming convention for use cases](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/domain-layer), where they suggest this naming:

> verb in present tense + noun/what (optional) + UseCase

with the following syntax to use it in Kotlin (example from [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/domain-layer)):

```
class FormatDateUseCase(userRepository: UserRepository) {

    private val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(
        userRepository.getPreferredDateFormat(),
        userRepository.getPreferredLocale()
    )

    operator fun invoke(date: Date): String {
        return formatter.format(date)
    }
}
```

### Question

Looking at the code above, we just have a class acting as a function. Why does Google recommend using these classes instead os just using top-level functions? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is not completely correct: We don't "have a class acting as a function", but you can say that each instance of the class acts as a function. That is important, since for instance, the constructor of `FormatDataUseCase` has a parameter of type `UserRepository`.

So, if we wanted to convert the `FormatDataUseCase` into a top-level function, it would not have the same signature as the `invoke` function of `FormatDataUseCase`, but it should also have `userRepository` as an additional parameter:

```kotlin
fun formatDateUseCase(userRepository: UserRepository, date: Date): String {
        val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(
            userRepository.getPreferredDateFormat(),
            userRepository.getPreferredLocale()
        )
        return formatter.format(date)
    }
```

And that is probably the main advantage of the recommended approach: You can have often-needed parameters and values automatically injected when you inject the use case class. This hides the dependencies from the caller of the use case, and makes it more comfortable to use.

Also, in the example the `SimpleDateFormat` is just initialized once and then reused for every call of the function, but if we converted it to a function, we would need to create a new instance on each call.

Comment: Yeah, I now see the advantages it provides over a top-level functions. However, the sake of being rigorous, an instance acting as a method is something that still breaks the semantics of nouns and verbs. 

I have mixed feelings about this usage, it is definitely using some Kotlin syntactic sugar to provide a simple API for the user, but I am afraid that it can lean towards more people using classes as methods anywhere else.

Nonetheless, thanks for your answer! I now have more context on this usage.